# C++ New Objects

Tags: c++, object, compiler-errors

I am learning C++ and I can not figure this out. I do not want to post all my code but feel that it is necessary as it is overall short.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MathObject.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int args, char *argv[]){
    MathObject mo = new MathObject(3,4);
    int sum = mo.sum();

    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MathObject.h"
using namespace std;

MathObject :: MathObject(int n, int m){
   num1 = n;
   num2 = m;
}

int MathObject :: sum(){
    return num1+num2;
}
```

---

```
class MathObject{
private:
    int num1;
    int num2;

public:
    int sum();
    MathObject(int n, int m);
};
```

So this is all in 3 separate files, I am using an example from my prof as a template on how to make classes and header files to organize our code. This always returns the error:

```
  conversion from 'MathObject*' to non-scalar type 'MathObject' requested| ||=== Build     finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

I have been going over the code for a while now but I can not get it! If anyone can point out what is wrong I would love to hear.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using multiple files, it may often help to visibly show them separately. Especially here where it appears that you have twice included the header files without guards.

Comment: `new` returns  pointer. In most cases, you cannot instantiate an object from a pointer. So you can't do this: `MathObject mo = new MathObject(3,4);`.

Comment: `instead of  MathObject mo = new MathObject(3,4);` use `MathObject mo(3,4);`

Comment: Side note: your header needs include guards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ you can just make an object on the stack:

```
MathObject mo(3,4);
```

This statement creates a `MathObject` called `mo` on the stack, that will be automatically destroyed when `main` returns. This should be your preferred way of creating objects.

The `new` operator in C++, unlike the `new` operator in Java or C#, is not needed for creating an object and should generally be used very sparingly. It allocates memory from the heap for holding the object, which allows the object's lifetime to extend beyond the current function. But that also means that you are responsible for cleaning up with `delete` after you are done using the object, or the memory will be leaked.

```
MathObject *mo = new MathObject(3,4); // Never do this!
```

This is terrible code. It's a) inefficient (allocating from the heap with `new` is much more expensive than the stack) and b) unsafe, because if for some reason you fail to `delete mo;` (sometimes the reason is out of your control, such as an exception being thrown through your code) the memory is leaked.

```
std::unique_ptr<MathObject> mo(new MathObject(3,4));
```

This uses `new` to create a `MathObject` object on the heap, and stores the returned pointer in a `unique_ptr` object created on the stack. The `unique_ptr` object will automatically `delete` the pointer stored in it when the `unique_ptr` is destroyed. This is safe, but it's still much slower than the first version.

Comment: You say never do this: `MathObject *mo = new MathObject(3,4);`, but if an object is very large and there is not enough space for it on the stack, you have to store it on the heap, is there a better way?

Comment: @Akavall Use `std::unique_ptr` or a similar smart pointer, which is covered in the next paragraph :)

Comment: Thanks, I guess the phrase "the unique_ptr object is allocated on the stack" confused a C++ noob like me.

Comment: I really appreciate all your answers. I do need to use heap based pointers (that is the profs preference) as we are also learning about destructors and memory management. (I cant get the code to format in comments) I will try this tonight. MathObject *mo = new MathObject(3,4); The objects in C++ seem move confusing than in java

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of MathObject is faulty. If you are dynamically allocating a MathObject, it should be

```
MathObject * mo = new MathObject(3,4);
```

And the sum function should be called using -> operator like this:

```
int sum = mo->sum();
```

Or if you want to create an object on the stack, you should not be using the new operator.

```
MathObject mo(3,4);
int sum = mo.sum();
```

That will do the trick.

Edit:

**Here is how it works on the top level:**
The new operator searches for the free memory for your object (In your case that is a MathObject), and initializes a new object in the space using the constructor arguments you passed. Then, it returns a pointer to this newly created object. So on the lhs, you should be declaring a pointer that can point to a MathObject. That is why we have `MathObject * mo` and not `Mathobject mo.`

I hope that helps!

Comment: IMHO you should warn users that when using `new` with raw pointers a `delete` must follow at some point in the future (unless they feel like leaking memory :) ).

Comment: I agree, generally speaking you should probably warn people about using raw pointers at all!

Comment: @MattCoubrough Actually, it creates an automatic storage duration object. But "stack" is definitely less confusing than "static".

Comment: @juanchopanza, Is that what the spec refers to it as? What a mouthful!

Comment: @MattCoubrough yes. The standard doesn't use "stack" and "heap" (though it does use the term "stack unwinding"...) They are technically implementation details, but no compiler writer in their right mind would put automatic-storage-duration objects on the heap.

Comment: @T.C. Good to know thanks, and it's critical that specs are not open to ambiguity; although I do think "stack" and "heap" are easier to use in everyday conversation with fellow programmers *as long as everyone  understands the intended meaning*.

Answer (score 0):

It's your object initalisation, here:

```
   MathObject mo = new MathObject(3,4);
```

You create a local object `mo`, then you you create another object somewhere on the heap and `new` returns a pointer to it. So your compiler understands that you want to assign a pointer to mo.

Replace your line with:

```
MathObject mo = MathObject(3,4);
```

or even:

```
MathObject mo(3,4);
```

Please note that these two forms give in fact the same result:  in both case, the compiler generates only one object and one call to the constructor with the parameter(3,4), despite the "=" operator.  To know more about this, look at:  http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/001.htm .

Comment: `MathObject mo = MathObject(3,4);` is temporary object construction followed by copy initialization. Compilers will usually do copy elision, but it's not required.

Comment: @T.C. in fact for years I thought exactly as you ! Then I stumbled over chapter 12.6.1 of the ISO standard.  It's about explicit initialization and says "Alternatively, a single assignment-expression can be specified as an initializer using the = form of initialization".  You are nevertheless true that some compilers use a temp and optimise it, because the standard says that either direct initialisation or copy initialisation can apply.

Comment: And if you look at examples supplied in the first paragraph, it makes clear that when `=` is used, a temporary is constructed and then copied/moved. 8.5/p14 defines `T x = a;` as copy initialization.

Answer (score 0):

the way you are creating a new object is how you would do it in `C#` or `Java`. 
in C++ it is better to avoid using `new` because you will have to keep memory management in mind and also it is much slower.

the little piece of code shows you how to use constructors:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class  MathObject{

    public:
    MathObject (){
        cout<<"Calling Default constructor"<<endl;
    }

    MathObject (int i, int j){
        x = i;
        y = j;
        cout<<"Calling constructors with two parameters"<<endl;
    }
    private:
    int x, y;
};


int main () {

    MathObject mo;
    MathObject mo2(3,4);

}
```

output:

> Calling Default constructor
>   Calling constructors with two parameters